# Installing Heroku Toolbelt Ubuntu unmet dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I am trying to install heroku toolbelt for Ubuntu using the following command

```
sudo wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

I get the following error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 heroku-toolbelt : Depends: heroku (= 3.99.4) but 6.11.7-1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I previously had heroku installed but the version was deprecated and the error presits after using the `gem update heroku` command
any ideas

Comment: Try sudo apt-get install heroku

Comment: I get: `heroku is already the newest version.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not the right script. Use `wget -qO- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh`

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to install the latest version of Heroku on all currently supported versions of Ubuntu by installing the Heroku snap package. Snap packages are standalone packages, so you won't get any  unmet dependencies errors when installing the Heroku snap package. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install --classic heroku
```

This is the recommended way of installing Heroku CLI in Ubuntu at the [Heroku Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) website.